# Reverse of concatenation in a specific dimension

Tags: python, pytorch

I am working with vision transformer (ViT). In one of its steps, the class token is concatenated with the tensor in a specific dimension (dim=1) and I want to remove the class token that has been concatenated. How I can do this?

```
batch_class_token = self.class_token.expand(n, -1, -1)
x = torch.cat([batch_class_token, x], dim=1)
```